# Why is Stack Overflow so clunky when pasting C++ code?

Tags: discussion

I love the site, but why is Stack Overflow so clunky when pasting [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) code?

Is there something I'm missing? What if I have a really long program, that seems rather redundant and annoying to do every time I paste C++ code.

For instance, I paste my code (*after indenting four space*s)... (I had to post a picture of it, because Stack Overflow won't let me post unformatted code.)

[image]

...**And it looks like that.**

Comment: I usually indent the code in my editor already and paste it without problems. If you lose the indentation that might be due to your browser...

Comment: You shouldn't be posting a "really long program". You should be posting a **minimal** compilable example.

Comment: Are you [first indenting and then pasting your code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254638/misunderstanding-how-the-make-code-sample-button-works)? If so, this probably counts as a duplicate of the linked post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to just paste the code. Then highlight it with your mouse and hit Ctrl + K.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way in my opinion and what I usually do would be taking care of the indentation in your editor already. For example with gedit (just the editor I happen to use on this netbook for easy tasks.) I do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the text
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent it all
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the text again (otherwise gedit won't pick up the new indentation for the first line...)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.

Now you just gotta paste it into your question and it is properly formatted. I find this way faster than switching to the mouse.