# Stack Snippets being misused

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

Not long after the general [introduction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/1364007) of Stack Snippets, there are already some posts that use them wrongly.

Today I came across a question with a stack-snippet containing CasperJS code which is JavaScript, but not runnable in the browser. I removed the snippet indicators from the post.

This would likely happen often, because new users don't know how code formatting works. They find a button that says *Code snippet* and click it to include their code. Code will be indented properly (I mean the first four spaces), and they are happy and don't care that there is a button to run non-working code.

Is there anything that can be done to teach users when to use stack-snippets? I don't think automatic detection is possible.

Comment: Admittedly I've not used the feature yet, but the first thing that came to my mind is if a user includes a snippet, before it's posted, the system could run the code, and if anything fails, throws errors etc, it alerts the user saying "The Stack Snippet you've included does not run. Are you sure you want to post this question?".

Comment: @TomHart but isn't that why people would post a stack snippet, because it doesn't run and they need help to make it work?

Comment: So what sense makes a "run" button on a code snippet for "My code does not run/compile - why?" type of question? Also I would rather have a default that makes the code as a code section, and you have the option to allow running it from browser. In order to allow running it, it needs to run successfully (either on SO server or in OP browser).

Comment: Saw one containing only XAML this morning...

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25932955/revisions) used it for C# code :(

Comment: It would be nice if it would look at the tags to determine wether or not to put the snippet markup in the question.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25928649/revisions) used it for PHP. [This one too](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25928830/revisions) which is a jQuery/JavaScript question but did not use stack snippets for what it should.

Comment: I already had a question that had a Stack-Snippet for Tomcat's `web.xml` file, and the snippet said the XML content was JS

Comment: I've seen questions using these for C++ and Java questions as well.  Can we automatically convert the snippet into a regular code block if it's not tagged with javascript/html/css?

Comment: Indeed, getting quite tired of seeing Java misrepresented as a javascript snippet, I decided to see how it happens by beginning a dummy question.  Turns out that if you press the handy code snippet icon, **you are never given an obvious opportunity to state the language** nor any warning that this entry method is apparently only appropriate for javascript.  That is a serious BUG!

Comment: @TomHart And for problems that do not manifest on _all_ systems? That may be browser-specific?

Comment: @sevenseacat & tom, It could run something like [Bootstrap's **Let Me Validate That for You**](https://github.com/cvrebert/lmvtfy) that automatically checks for HTML validation errors when users submit issues that link to running code.  Of course, non-working code is welcome on a question and answer site, but if there's an obvious console error, it might be helpful to prevent typo questions.

Comment: Can't this post be useful for warn/error check invalid code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet

Comment: @LGSon That seems like a good idea. AFAIK, you're the first one to have that (specific) idea. One problem that I might see is what happens when (1) the OP is learning a language and doesn't yet fully grasp the syntax or (2) the snippet is supposed to contain an error and the OP is asking about the error. What happens when the errors confuse the language detection engine in such a way that the language is misdetected? The misdetection can happen in both directions (browser languages vs other languages). If you can address those concerns and propose good UI, I'd like to see such a feature reques

Comment: I just want to note that in the majority of questions with non-working snippets, the question originally contained only code blocks, and the snippets were introduced later by other people editing.

Comment: @MrLister Really? I haven't seen even once I think. I would suggest to @ reply to those editors that this is not ok (there is no auto-completion). They will get a notification of your comment. I you see the same user making the same dumb edit even after correspondence, then it should be escalated with a mod flag.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Difficult to find examples of non working snippets now; I'll let you know as soon as I find some.

Comment: If you can fully automatically detect, I think you've solved the halting problem.

Answer (score 68):

There are probably things we can do to improve the guidance here, and I expect they'll become more obvious as more people find and use it. We're open to all suggestions.

That said... This isn't the end of the world. In fact, properly-formatted code with a useless "run" button on it may be an *improvement* over the status quo in cases where folks were previously struggling to format their code properly. Particularly for HTML, which could result in a big chunk of a post that wasn't even *visible* if the author forgot to indent it.

Comment: While "Stack-snippet" is a cool name, something as simple as changing that to contain a verb might help. "Runnable snippet", for example. Or check if it's the first time they've used that feature and, if so, display a message explaining it.

Comment: I like that second suggestion

Comment: Agreed on the second one! @codeMagic the first one didn't go over so well...[Is there a better name for Stack Snippets?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270131/is-there-a-better-name-for-stack-snippets)

Comment: @Dan yeah but they were just looking for other names instead of a specific reason for needing a new name. Especially to someone new, this name isn't going to be very explicit. But I do agree the second idea would be more powerful. The first was more far a quick "fix"

Comment: The name "Stack Snippet" sounds like GitHub's Gist feature.

Comment: In honour of @codeMagic 's suggestion, I suggest renaming Stack Snippets to `Code Magic` ... ;-)

Comment: The "Code snippet" button is maybe just *too close* of the simple formating tools like "Code Sample"  (Or "Image" actually) ?

Comment: And for the "polemic" comment: Why not only *show* the "Code snippet" button starting at some reputation level ? This won't prevent its usage by typing in markdown. Only prevent "lazy" click on the button -- and actually triggering some user questioning at some point "Hey, what's this *new* button on the editor?" "How is it different from the 'other one' ?"

Comment: Perfect example here...[Stack-snippet for Android code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025188/unable-to-instantiate-activity)

Comment: I'm still dealing with this issue.  Just this morning, some noob posted three giant chunks of PHP within the "JavaScript" and "HTML" panes of three snippets.  I'm also not sure the feature is living up to itself.  I still use jsFiddle because I find it easier, and I would say most new postings are using jsFiddle more than the snippets.

Comment: "web snippet"? or "html snippet"?

Comment: See also now http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334901/visually-group-code-and-snippet-icons-and-clarify-which-one-to-use

Answer (score 27):

Well, why is every user able to post a Stack-Snippet? I often see questions from users with very low quality where they want to post images of their database or things like this - but they actually can't cause they don't have enough rep. They just post the link of the image. Then, an user with more rep can decide to include the images or leave it as it is.

Why don't we make this for Stack-Snippets too? Users that post an HTML/JS-related question can't use Stack-Snippets, so they can watch users with more rep editing some questions to include Stack-Snippets and others not. Then, when they achieve enough rep to post Stack-Snippets, they could already know when and how to use them.

This won't actually resolve all misuse of Stack-Snippets, but I'm sure it will decrease the misuse of it.

Comment: Interesting idea, that would protect the community against some harmful, one-shot code. The question is, whether this might even be a problem. Are there users that actively want to harm other users with snippets by freezing the browser or something else?

Comment: And this doesn't actually solve the misuse, because even users that have slightly more rep to use snippets don't know how to use them, because there is still no hints in the UI. I think this would only delay the inevitable.

Comment: @ArtjomB. *"it will decrease the misuse of it."*

Answer (score 15):

Don't fix users. Fix code.

It's a common theme over on UX.SE, how to deal with mistakes by users. One common pattern is that if you can detect the mistake, and if you have a reasonable idea what was intended, then just do what's intended. As a bonus, you may give the user a hint that there's an easier method - but only bother with that if the "correct" method is in fact easier.

So here the problem is rather straightforward: if the input definitely isn't a code snippet, just convert it to formatted code.

Implementing this is probably easiest done at the moment of posting: "Trying to run code snippet... Failed to run code snippet. Removing Run button."

Comment: Have you ever heard of the halting problem? TL;DR "simply run the code snippet once when posting" is a nontrivial problem. Furthermore, this would require SO to implement a JS runtime on their backend - currently the task of executing the snippets is handled by the browser of the users.

Comment: @l4mpi: Of course. I don't care particularly if the code halts or not. If it halts, it's runnable code, and if it doesn't halt, it's also runnable code. Plus you'd run the code as a first step while posting, in the browser of whoever is doing the posting. The result can be faked of course, but the intent here is to deal with Murphy not Machiavelli.

Comment: The snippet simply runs in the poster's browser and if it doesn't halt, the poster is prevented from posting bad code. If it produces errors, then it will be converted back plain code block.

Comment: Things are probably more complex. For example _"why the following code does not stop"_ might leads to a perfectly valid code snippet. But never "halting" though... Not mentioning code snippets are not only targeted at JavaScript and al. This is only a first step. And to quote a common question in an other popular tag _"Why that code does not compile"_ might lead to a perfectly valid code snippet ... obviously not "working"...

Comment: Running the snippet _in the OPs browser_ is even worse than running it on the backend. Can't you imagine how annoying it would be to click through alerts generated by a snippet before posting? Or in the worst case, not being able to post as the snippet code demonstrates an issue which crashes the JS runtime of the browser? You would make the experience worse for all of the users who are actually intelligent enough for the feature in the first place. I'd rather recommend "don't fix users, downvote them until they either learn or leave". And it's really not that hard to learn in this case...

Comment: @l4mpi: If it's already annoying to the poster, it shouldn't be posted in the first place. If it crashes the browser of the poster, it shouldn't be posted. Your objections are actually reasons why we should want this.

Comment: @MSalters you seem to be unable to think of the many legitimate questions which would be affected by your proposal. E.g. "How do I work around this bug [insert snippet demonstrating bug] which [crashes the Tab/causes 20s lag/does other annoying thing] in [insert browser here]?" - Should the user download another browser which doesn't exhibit the bug to post that question? Also, alerts can be perfectly legitimate parts of a snippet, and even if it's just one it would cause needless annoyance for the poster. And all that for a non-problem because some people are stupid? No thanks.

Comment: `alert` is really, really easy to replace with `function () {}` for testing, though.

Comment: Just a comment on "do what's intended". Please don't ever do that. Feel free to suggest what you think the intention is, but just in case that isn't it, don't do it automatically. Perl tries to do what you mean. Haven't you ever run into Perl completely mangling your actual meaning? Especially when you change "just a small thing" and the interpreter changes its guess. In an unrelated part of code.

Comment: You’re of course entirely right, and the amount of user-blaming to defend this terrible UI here on Meta is simply breath-taking.

Comment: Hear, hear. Software should adapted to how users *actually* use it, not some idealised or theoretical scenario. And not the other way around.

Answer (score 11):

It's been awhile but a [recent post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296983/lots-of-bogus-begin-snippet-need-to-be-edited-out-because-of-unrelated-languag) made me want to come back and check on this. With the support that [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused#comment95411_271649) seemed to get and since this is still an issue, I think I should add it as an answer.

**Quick and easy fix**

My first, possibly less popular idea, was simple--change the name to be more explicit. I realize the naming has been [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270131/is-there-a-better-name-for-stack-snippets) but that seems to be because someone didn't care for it. Here there is an explicit reason for doing so (to make it more clear what it should be used for).

My one example is "Runnable snippet" because this, or something similar, tells the user that it should be able to do something.

[This comment was also a good suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused#comment95547_271649) :P

**A little more complex but probably more effective**

Check if it's the first time they've used that feature and, if so, display a message explaining it (what it should do, when to use it, etc...).

This one would take a little more to implement but still shouldn't be too exhausting and it will likely be more useful than simply changing the name.

This could possibly be rep related, as well. Show the box with explanation every time a user tries to use it in a post until they reach a certain rep threshold (50 maybe).

Comment: The naming is first step in the right direction, but it shouldn't stop. I still haven't seen a proposal that fixes every problem and is intuitive.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I agree. But I think my second suggestion would help quite a bit with people using them incorrectly.

Answer (score 9):

Could the tooltip of the Code snippet be extended to something like "Code snippet - only for JavaScript and Html" or "Code snippet - only for browser runnable code"?

As users put everything there Java, C++, even SQL queries... Such tooltip would prevent at least some of this rubbish.

Comment: Dude. Letting a browser run Java, C++ or SQL code would have been a revolutionary invention.

Answer (score 7):

Although it will not completely solve the problem of misuse, would it be possible to read the tags when the question is asked and if there isn't a tag related to what code snippets can display
([javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) etc.) then either warn the user that a code snippet may not be suitable or automatically convert the code snippet block to a regular code block.

While this wouldn't solve all of the problems it should help to combat users using it for php, c++ or other unintended languages.

Comment: Since there are many more tags that have nothing to do with the currently supported snippet languages, this is a good filter. The question is what to do. Warnings will be clicked away. I propose a modal: ***Your code does not appear to be a runnable snippet in the browser. Do you want to post it as simple code? - Yes / No***

Answer (score 6):

Why not make the code sample button (`{}`) open a window similar to the code snippet window? Currently, if someone clicks that the `{}` button when nothing is selected, it just adds a `enter code here` indented with 4 spaces. A new user might not be aware that for example they have to indent every line 4 spaces and not just the first one. What I suggest is that if nothing is selected, the `{}` button should open a window similar to the code snippet window, but suitable for any language. If something is selected, the `{}` button could indent the selected content 4 spaces like it does now so that it's not too difficult to indent. When nothing is selected, the `{}` button could do something like this:

[image]

The user would enter their code in the window and wouldn't have to indent it 4 spaces. Clicking "Save & insert into post" would automatically indent the code 4 spaces like for code snippets, except it wouldn't add a "Run" button. It could also detect if there is a list right before the code and indent 8 spaces if needed (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3792/349538)).

There would also be some useful things in the left of the window. There could be Language dropdown list which would automatically generate an HTML comment for syntax highlighting (the list of languages could be the list of supported languages [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/349538)), and maybe a Tidy button like there already is for code snippets (though a Tidy button may cause some issues with Python or similar languages).

For example, the if the user enters the following, it would output the following markdown code:

[image]

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

    #include <ctype.h>

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(letter); i++){
        letter[i] = tolower(letter[i]);
    }
```

This would have the advantage of being more user-friendly to new users so there would be less badly formatted code.

Maybe if the user enters code in a snippet that doesn't look like HTML, javascript or CSS, the system could suggest they switch to the above window.

Comment: I like this suggestion. The only issue I see is that this would probably not consistent. Ctrl+K is a shortcut for the `{}` button. The editor window doesn't indent the marked code when the tab key is pressed. This means Ctrl+K is the only shortcut to quickly indent code. If the overlay UI is being presented when Ctrl+K is pressed, then it would likely piss off some (power) users that don't need the overlay. But opening the overlay on button click and not on shortcut key press would not be consistent.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I actually thought that it should only do that if nothing is selected, and have the current behavior when something is selected, but I just noticed I forgot to mention it. I will edit to clarify that.

Comment: This deserves to be a proper feature request, instead of being buried below 7 answers like it is now.

Answer (score 5):

I think the mistaken snippets will be very quickly identified. Once identified, it's just a matter of editing out `begin-snippet` and `end-snippet` lines.

1. As a note for new users, we can have a banner on top of the snippet editor saying "Do not include code that uses external libraries" (or something appropriate). Optionally, remove the banner for users having 20+ reputation (or some suitable threshold).
2. It would be great if we could mark a snippet as non-runnable, and system can automatically remove the start and end tags, and make it an edit. That would be an efficient way to demote non-runnable snippets to normal code listings, without consuming much time of editors and reviewers.

Comment: 1. jQuery and angularJS are *external libraries* and can be included. What if the poster wants to include jQuery UI? The wording is not right in this case. How about *Do not include code which is not appropriate for browsers?*.

Comment: re. 2 What is a useful definition of 'non-runnable'?

Comment: @dcorking: Using code snippets for Node.js or Node-Webkit code listings, for example.

Comment: Now you changed *flag* to *mark*. I would agree if this would only be usable for 2k+ users. Low-rep users should not be trusted with such a tool without community consensus (read: reviewing).

Comment: @ArtjomB.: It would be an unreviewed edit. <2k user, can identify a wrong code snippet. Then a >2k user can review the edit. Only then the edit will be effective.

Comment: Here it is, three months later, and I'm still seeing this problem every day. Looks like the mistakes aren't being identified, or the users aren't being educated, or both.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's simply a case of removing the 'begin snippet', 'end snippet' tags to convert back to a code block, a button in the editor window to convert to 'code block' would help those editing the post and might also give the OP a visual clue that there is another way of posting code.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a `runnable: false` directive to the snippet opening?

Until the 'run' button inside the snippet editor is clicked, don't allow the directive to change. Once it *has* run, change the directive automatically.

That way, anyone posting dangerous code will have to do it to themselves first. And if that code crashes the browser tab, say, then they will never be able to light up the "Run" button.

(I've [already proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295634/1677912) using the `runnable: false` directive to disable the widget for non-runnable code.)

Comment: That's a great idea, but I think there are some problems with this approach regarding the syntax hightlighting. Posting Python code or Java code as HTML (it's the first box after all) will lead to unhighlighted code. This is not bad, but also not perfect and still needs someone to fix that (At least I *hate* unhighlighted code). Also, if implemented, the runnedness of a stack snippet should be copied along with it when the snippet is copied to your own answer.