# Make Stack Snippets more visible and encourage their use

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

A lot of people (especially new users) don't know about this feature.

It would help us a lot if the OP would use the snippet in his question. Answering time can be radically reduced.

Now, I see that the snippet is not used as much as it should, especially when we are dealing with simple JavaScript questions.

1) If the question includes just JavaScript, HTML and CSS, the snippet pop-up should appear to the user and ask him to include his code in the snippet. He can close the snippet if he feels that the code cannot be run in the snippet. This will also increase the quality of some questions.

2) Whenever a JSFiddle link is inserted, tell users with a small text under the snippet icon that we have the snippet feature. Going to JSFiddle when we have the snippet is wasted time.

Comment: This would lead to a lot of posts [having snippets unnecessarily](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271647/3366929).

Comment: If someone adds a jsfiddle link pop up a little flag pointing to the snippets button, "Hey, you can add runnable snippets here!"

Comment: @Will I like that idea

Comment: Can you tell me how to put Materul-UI, react-router, redux, styled compotes and unit tests inside the Stack Snippets?