# Add information on Stack Snippets to Help Center

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, help-center

There isn't currently any page on the Stack Overflow help center that relates to Stack Snippets, and a search for that term in the help center does not return any valid results.

I have twice used a link to the [last official meta post announcing the feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) as a reference when leaving a comment suggesting that users provide code in the form of a working snippet.  However, that's not an ideal reference page, and even it is getting hard to find when searching Meta, buried under more recent discussions of bugs and feature requests.

So, a clear help page with the basic how-to would be useful to have as a canonical reference.  It should of course be cross-linked with the help page on [minimal, complete, and verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was about to ask this question, especially since on the [ask] page it still promotes jsbin and sqlfiddle, but doesn't even mention [so]'s own features.

Comment: Some related meta questions requesting additional visibility for Snippets: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271796/777586), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271796/777586), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315235/777586)