# Where should I link new users for guidance on using Stack Snippets?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, help-center

I frequently see new users turn up whose JavaScript example could quite easily be made an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by making it a Stack Snippet. Rather than risk confusing them by editing it in, it might be best to link them to a page with authoritative documentation.

I've tried these options:

- [Searching for *snippet* on the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=snippet) gives nothing.
- [Searching for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq%20stack-snippets?mode=all) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)[stack-snippets](/questions/tagged/stack-snippets) on meta gives nothing.
- [This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers?noredirect=1&lq=1) is outdated, and clearly a community review request.
- [This blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is outdated, and clearly more of an announcement.

At the moment the best workflow I can come up for this involves taking a screenshot myself, circling the button with freehand red pen, et cetera. You know, the sort of thing a documentation page should be doing.

Comment: It is absolutely a problem that Stack Snippets are not documented (that I can find) anywhere in the Help Center *or* in the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Personally, I've never paid much attention to this because they are completely unhelpful for all of the languages that I deal with. I spend most of my time editing out pointless snippets in C++ questions. But if we're going to have the feature, and we're going to expect people to use it, then we need to be doing a better job of documenting it.

Comment: As such, this is essentially a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277340/add-information-on-stack-snippets-to-help-center, unless you actually want to focus on the question in the title (where, currently, the answer seems to be "nowhere"). If you'd like, you can create a new Meta question on using Stack Snippets, tag with the [meta-tag:faq-proposed] tag, and ping me to have it marked as community wiki.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree with the first option: I think snippet documentation belongs in the help center. Could you close this as a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277340/add-information-on-stack-snippets-to-help-center ?