# Code Snippet as a formatting tool

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, stack-snippets

Since the Stack Snippet is [being misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused), let us make it a feature!

My proposal is to add a dropdown to select the language, and let people paste their code inside to format the code. The language hint to trigger Stack Snippet is not added for any languages other than HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

The default option in the dropdown should detect the language based on tag, using the same tag-based detection supply to Google Code Prettify.

What do you guys think?

Comment: yes, please I am sick of editing tons of VBA code as snippets...