# Force preview of stack snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662210/php-total-cost), among many, **many**, others, attempts to run PHP code in a stack snippet.

I propose that the stack snippets are each previewed in a dialog box after the user clicks <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd>. Each snippet preview will have a header that says "Is this runnable snippet useful to the post?" The subheader should say "Click yes to keep and no to remove the runnable snippet -- your code will still stay in the post." What the buttons do is self explanatory. The poster can (hopefully) decide whether or not the snippet is useful or not.

Comment: Why not just explicitly disable them on questions with tags that are not going to be capable of running them?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274636/code-snippet-as-a-formatting-tool

Comment: @Makoto I was considering that, but I know I came across a handful of questions tagged php, when their snippet was only html/css.

Comment: @Mooseman: And those questions should have been retagged, anyway. That would then enable the snippetting.

Comment: Good idea in theory, but probably useless in practice. People who don't read the labels on the code snipped textboxes (it says HTML/CSS/JS right there) won't read the preview either. And as demonstrated by a few thousand people every day, most askers are either unable or unwilling to get basic formatting right, even with help and a preview shoved right in their face.

Comment: I think the details of this proposal need to be expanded for it to be useful. The preview should not constantly be rendered, and so it cannot be "forced" in its entirety. When would the preview show? At every keypress? At set intervals? Prior to submit with a confirmation? Would it apply to all tags or only to tags which are compatible with the stack snippet? Overall this request needs more description.

Answer (score 35):

*sigh* I told you so. The vast vast vast majority of people who post to these sorts of tags are not bright enough or do not care enough to use the "snippet" feature properly. They see a code snippet button and press it then ignore the outcome. Now we have a bunch of mess across SO.

The snippet functionality should be *at least* disabled on non-candidate code. SO already does a pretty good job at guessing the language of code blocks so I can't imagine this'd have a high failure rate. For mistagged questions where that might fail, well, those questions will need retagging anyway don't they?

Going further than this comes under the umbrella of a previous question: [Stack Snippets being misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271647/560648)

Comment: Leaving aside the correlation between IQ and question tags, which strikes me as tendentious, I think that with the possible exception of some very specific domains, the semantic difference between "sample" and "snippet" does not help decide which one to use. And since both of those phrases are hidden behind possibly obscure graphic symbols, it is quite conceivable that the one a given user chooses for their code is simply the one they first stumble upon. (The two symbols are not even contiguous, so there is not even a strong clue that another alternative exists.) IOW, UI not IQ.