# Abusing the Code Snippet for wrong languages

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I see this at least once a day, someone puts their Java or even C code in the **Code Snippet** thing that's meant exclusively for HTML / CSS / JS.

What it means - someone has to manually remove the magic snippet comments from the post.

Usual result:

```js
package net.mightypork.rcalc;

public class ParseError extends RuntimeException {

 public ParseError(String message) {

  super(message);
 }

 public ParseError(Exception e) {

  super(e);
 }

}
```

Obviously the "Run code snippet" button doesn't do anything, it is not runnable in a browser.

The **button for inserting snippet** has a tooltip "Code snippet Ctrl-M".

That, of course, sounds like a general code snippet. A newbie then puts their code in either of the fields and lets it be.

Proposal - **more descriptive tooltip**, eg. "Web code snippet" or something similar. Also maybe a warning within the snippet that it is ONLY for those languages.

Comment: You could even change the text to be "Stack Snippet Ctrl-M", since I thought that was the name chosen for this feature.

Comment: A couple of thoughts:  a future goal is for it to support more languages than just web-based languages, and we've had several discussions about this before; people that want to use a snippet are often using the wrong language for it.

Comment: @Makoto They haven't really indicated any intent to support other languages.  HTML/CSS/JavaScript is easy because they already know that every single site user has a working interpreter for that code built right into their browser, which they need to access the site in the first place.  To support other languages they'd need to build in the support to compile, run, and interact with the program, and they'd need to do it *for each language they wanted to support*.

Comment: @Servy: I'm pretty sure they did...[it even says so in the tag excerpt](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-snippets).

Comment: Technically maybe they could somehow team up with ideone or similar service and use that... but for now there is really no other language, and noobs keep mistaking this for just using indentation.

Comment: @Makoto The entire basis for that statement is a quote of one dev saying, "it's possible".  He didn't say that SE was actually planning to implement it.

Comment: Probably shouldn't even be shown unless the question has an HTML, CSS or jquery tags....

Comment: Maybe it could check if the code in the snippet is what is declared eg "js"... and if not, don't show the preview buttons thing?

Comment: @Will There are a lot of languages that are built on top of HTML/CSS/Javascript and for many of those questions *only* those tags are used, not HTML/CSS/Javascript.  The list would likely get pretty long, and would take a fair bit of maintenance work.  You'd pretty much have to have some sort of option, say when editing the tag wiki, for whether or not stack snippets applied to that tag.

Comment: [related post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused/271649#comment97932_271649)?

Comment: yep appears to be pretty much the same. we can close this. But really this is a thing that needs to be solved, that other Q is from September!

Comment: I agree @MightyPork and I think the guy who suggested in a comment to have some notification to new users when attempting to use it was on to something ;)

Comment: I don't agree that the now marked duplicate link question fits since it is not a [feature-request]. Nevertheless, I think this is not a good feature-request, because the user who posted arbitrary code as html/css/js deliberately disregarded the signs (named quarters, additional js-library options). They're not going to care about the exact wording of the button text. It has to be more blunt.

Comment: I honestly didn't think that nobody would bat an eye when I said jQuery instead of javascript.  Wow, it really has become synonymous.

Comment: @Will "JavaScript, or jQuery for short, is a scripting language for browsers..."

Comment: I've already read [Stack Snippets being misused](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused). What is the current status of this feature-request ? Could it be reactivated ?

Comment: I have to agree with @ArtjomB. In the text where they're pasting the code, it says "HTML", "JavaScript", or "CSS" in the top right corner. Adding more text for people who don't read anyways is a waste of time.

Comment: Another plausible solution: upon clicking the code snippet icon, pop up a dialog that asks something like "Are you adding CSS, JavaScript and/or HTML to your post?" If no, then inform them that other languages should be added like {directions here}.

Comment: related feature-request: [Replace code snippets by normal code block if JavaScript tag is absent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276409/1048572)

Comment: Can't this post give some idea's how to warn/error check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet