# Tip new/old users about the new “Stack Snippet” function

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, editor

This comment at the [How to make JavaScript recognize backspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781497/how-to-make-javascript-recognize-backspace/32781714#comment53401324_32781497) post refers 
to the fact that off site code snippet runners like http://www.jsfiddle.net is less good than on site runners when it comes to having both code and text available together in the future.

Wouldn't it be great to also hint users, like with a highlighted "Did you know...." tip just above the text editor, or maybe as a popup/bubble similar to the error message which say "you can't refer to fiddle without also having some code in your question/answer"?

Sample hint text.

> Did you know that using our new "Stack Snippet" function, you can
>   store live code on-site instead of off-site. This way your
>   post will have both the text and code available together in
>   the future, without the need of a third party site. 
>   You only have to write your code once, and it shows up as both code and a runnable demo inside your post.

I mean SO users have been forced to use off site snippet runners for quite some time and I think "pushing them a little" would be good as it is important to have QA's here more future proofed with both text and code on site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until we figure out how to adequately prevent users from posting unsupported languages, I think this would create more problems than it would solve.  I've seen plenty of C# "Stack Snippets" that obviously don't work.

One problem is that the [Stack Snippets fail to communicate that they only support basic web development (HTML, javascript, CSS)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283108/abusing-the-code-snippet-for-wrong-languages).  For every web developer who takes advantage of this on-site feature (instead of jsFiddle, plnkr, codepen, etc), I think you'll see about 3 other users mistakenly post their C#/java/python code inside.

If people start consistently using Stack Snippets properly, I'll support this feature request.  Until then, I think this is a bad idea.

Comment: I wasn't aware of those issues and if they are the reason for not marketing the feature I understand your point.

Comment: The hint code popup when you find a link for jsfiddle for example. It could also be made so that it only pops up when the question is tagged html,css,js. As for your concern, I don't think there is a lot you can do.

Comment: What about this post to warn/error check invalid code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet

Comment: @LGSon that's up to the SO devs to implement.  But yeah if they did something like that (and it prevented misuse of Stack Snippets) then your feature request would be fine.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Do you know how/if jsfiddle prevent users from running C# snippets?

Comment: @LGSon C# simply won't compile on a js fiddle because C# and javascript aren't the same thing.  There is an equivalent online C# code running site called [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) that can run some of the core .NET framework, but SO does not support runnable C# in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that such tip could only be shown on specific cases:

1. There is a link to jsfiddle in the post
2. Or, the question is tagged with the appropriate tags (e.g html- JavaScript - css ....)