# automatic code snippet transformation with no reason [edit abusing]

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, stack-snippets

There is a lot of questions dealing about how code snippet aren't well used and in many cases, users are abusing of them thinking they may add value to their question. Here is some of them:

[Abusing the Code Snippet for wrong languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283108/abusing-the-code-snippet-for-wrong-languages)

[Code snippets are a pest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334675/code-snippets-are-a-pest)

---

My concern here is about low reputation users editing questions to transform html/css/js code to snippet **automatically** without paying attention to the question and its content and especially to the code. They are simply looking to edit as much question as possible to gain the +2 and it works well with code snippet because of two reasons:

1. There is no effort involved: select the code and click a button.
2. They are sure that this kind of edit will be considered since it will add many characters to the initial question.

So let's say it's a good and easy way to boost some stats. In the other hand, these kind of edits are also approved **automatically** by many users. When they see that there is a code transformation to a snippet they think it's a good edit so they approve it.

---

Here is a recent example among many others I face regularly: it's about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827178/simulate-background-image-with-attachment-fixed-using-picture) where I rejected the edit done by a user. In the question we can clearly read **"This is the abbreviated HTML."** so the OP shared a part of his code with no CSS and no full path; thus a code snippet transformation here is very bad and useless.

And if we take a look to the history we can see this:

[image]

- The user who edited the question has 13 suggestions rejected so I can conclude that some of them are like the above one, simple automatic code transformation.
- When checking the profile of the user who approved the edit, I see he's a .NET developer with a low activity on html/css questions so I can also conclude it was an automatic approve.

---

Here is another example where the edit was very dangerous and changed the question completely and made it irrelevant.

It's about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753688/fontawesome-replacement-on-li-tag-shows-empty-square): The OP was having an issue with Font Awesome 5 and I commented his question to see if he was using the JS or the CSS version because there is a huge difference and the JS version is leading to common issues. As expected, he was using the JS version BUT if we look at the edit history we will see a low reputation user editing his code to create a snippet and to include the CSS version (a pure **automatic edit**) and **the worst thing** is that he included a relative path of a CSS file.

By doing this he completely changed the meaning of the question and we can simply think that the OP is having trouble to correctly include the CSS file and the question may be closed as "a simple typographical error" which is not the case!

And what is even worse, is that this edit got approved by 2 users that are not active within the html/css questions so it was a clear **automatic approve**.

[image]

---

Considering this, a lot of questions can be asked:

- Should we add more restriction to code edit? Maybe some pop-up warning about a potential bad edit.
- Should we restrict code editing for low reputation user and make it available starting from a certain threshold?
- Transforming a code to a snippet should not be considered within the minimum values of character edit so we avoid such automatic edit
- We should add more *test edits<sup>1</sup>* including code snippet to prevent automatic approval and maybe ban users that fails in such tests from the suggestions edit queue for a while.

<sup>1: I am talking about the edits that are not real and used like captcha to see if a user is automatically approving/rejecting edits</sup>

I think something should be done as these kind of edits are not few cases. They are very common and I see them regularly.

***NB***: I am talking about questions dealing with html/css/js where the code snippet is concerned. I am not including ALL kind of code edits as there is lot of them improving the question and making it better (I myself do them). I am not saying that all the user are approving code edit without paying attention, many of them are approving/rejecting them in a good manner.

*My main concern is about automatic code edit done by low reputation users with no reason leading to useless/bad edit and in some cases making the question irrelevant.*

Comment: Hyperbole as a rhetorical device is a tricky one at meta, it does not often have the intended effect.

Comment: *We should add more test edits1 including code snippet to prevent automatic approval* I think this is a good idea assuming it's possible for poorly added stack snippets to be automatically generated. My understanding of the edit audits is that they're automatically generated, which is one reason why they're all so obviously bad.

Comment: I think the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) should also be updated to reflect when Stack Snippets should be added (only for HTML/CSS/JS questions, only when the snippet would recreate the issue the OP is having, etc.).

Comment: @BSMP yes and more precesiely when the code can be **fully run** within the question without lacking any lib or CSS include and when we are sure the OP included all the code and not only part of it

Answer (score 5):

Low reputation users have to have their edits pass through a review queue.  If users are actively approving their edits without them actually being beneficial, then that's cause enough to flag the reviewers and teach them about how we're actually meant to be reviewing edits.

If the user has more than 2K rep (to bypass the review queues), then that's also worthy of a moderator flag to indicate that this kind of behavior is slipping through the system.

I'm not convinced enough that this is a widespread *problem* that should require any other kind of mechanical or automatic intervention on behalf of the site.  Unless we can truly identify that the ability for us to delegate this to diamond moderators is starting to fall behind the amount of posts that this impacts, I don't believe that anything outside of flags are needed.

Comment: the main issue is that it's difficult to see this behavior ... if i open question that is already edited i won't always have the reflex to check the edit history to see if someone added a code snippet in a wrong way .. so i may start seeing the issue and thinking about something completely different from the OP intention.

Comment: Also if i identify such thing, there is no need to flag as i will simply rollback the edit ... but not everyone will do this. As i commented above, the bad is already made and people may start seeing the question differently and not thinking about a bad edit

Comment: You *should* be flagging this.  This is the only way the OP will actually get the message that they shouldn't be approving edits like that.