# "JavaScript snippet"? But I use it for HTML and CSS as well!

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, user-interface

Following on from various Meta posts about code snippets being misused ([like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277602/should-it-be-more-obvious-that-stack-snippets-are-only-meant-for-html-css-js) and [this other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused?lq=1)), a few days ago the Code Snippet WYSIWYG button's `title` was changed from "Code snippet" to  "JavaScript snippet":

> [image: JavaScript Snippet image]

The problem is that it isn't only used for JavaScript code. Myself and many others use the code snippet functionality a lot when answering HTML and CSS questions which feature no JavaScript at all. The phrase *JavaScript snippet* simply doesn't work in those cases.

Perhaps this should be renamed to "HTML/CSS/JavaScript snippet" or "Website code snippet" instead - something which doesn't make it sound like its only use is for JavaScript code.

In answers, perhaps the button could be hidden completely when the question isn't tagged with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), as well as [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3), [knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js) or [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) which are options within the code snippet interface.

---

```css
* {
    transition: 0.5s;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 108px;
  text-align: center;
}

body:hover {
  background: black;
}

body:hover span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span>&#9785;</span>
```

Comment: Better than "code snippet", which is what is was. And caused people to use it for every other language under the sun.

Comment: What do you do when someone askes a new question? It isn't tagged yet - do you hide the button or not?

Comment: @Oded I hadn't considered that. That could still apply to answers though, as I'm sure it isn't only misused in questions. I've updated the post.

Comment: @Oded also I'm not arguing that it isn't better than "code snippet", I'm pointing out that it has more uses than just JavaScript, but "JavaScript snippet" implies that its sole purpose is for JavaScript code.

Comment: I don't like "Website code snippet" because that still doesn't make it clear that it's not for languages like PHP. Maybe "HTML/CSS/JS snippet" if they decide to change it again.

Comment: I vote for `Insert self-contained runnable working client side website code snippet`

Comment: Well, that's a bit too long. Maybe "client-side web snippet "?

Comment: `Web snippet (but not for languages like PHP)`

Comment: I'd say copy the functionality of [ideone](https://ideone.com/) to support every language and change it back to "code snippet". You cannot support absolutely everything, libraries and maybe shaders are hard, but some `C`, `C++`, `Java` and `Python` would go a long way.

Comment: Why not just have a checkbox at the bottom of the window for `runnable` then have a `<select>` tag for each code block's language?

Comment: How about "Fiddle"? [That's what many people have taken to calling these things anyway regardless of whether they're actually hosted on jsfiddle.net.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark)

Comment: @BoltClock - The problem with that is there's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) too so just calling it a Fiddle still doesn't imply it's only for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: It's also a stupid name.

Comment: Nice JavaScript snippet!

Comment: trippy snippet man. Cool!

Comment: Hey, turn that frown upside down! ☺

Answer (score 68, accepted):

My suggestion:

- *Live demo (HTML/CSS/JS only)*

It makes clear what languages are supported, and is a clear indication that this is not just a "code snippet" or "code block" feature but an actual demonstration tool that will require language support to run.

It's also pithy. :)

Comment: This. Why obscure what it really is behind words like *Client-side*? Last I checked, I could run Java applets on the client, flash on the client, etc (although not as much as before, of course).

Comment: +1. Explicit is better than implicit, as the Python folks like to say.

Comment: [Looks like this has now been accepted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299236/1317805), so I've gone ahead and accepted this answer. Nice idea!

Comment: Whooo get in​​​

Answer (score 11):

*(FWIW, I prefer [Lightness Races in Orbit's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298808/157247) to this. This is much clunkier.)*

---

Wording suggestions:

- *Client-side web snippet (HTML, CSS, JS)*
- ***Runnable*** client-side web snippet (HTML, CSS, JS)
- ***Live*** client-side web snippet (HTML, CSS, JS)

I wouldn't hide the button if the question isn't tagged, because a lot of people (possibly most) write the question first then add tags.

But a check as of when they're *posting* would make sense. That's been requested in various forms [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295604/warning-when-snippet-mark-up-is-used-on-posts-not-tagged-with), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277602/should-it-be-more-obvious-that-stack-snippets-are-only-meant-for-html-css-js), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276409/replace-code-snippets-by-normal-code-block-if-javascript-tag-is-absent) (at least).

Comment: It might be useful in a small number of non-front end situations as well. I can think of some questions like *"How do I duplicate this HTML/CSS functionality in some GUI framework?"* as one.

Comment: Perhaps we could move the tag entry box to the top when writing a new question to encourage tags first?

Comment: @MattWilko: I think that's a good idea regardless. I've said it before, too!

Answer (score 5):

Back in the day the convention was to call this DHTML. It meant HTML, CSS & Javascript running in a browser environment. The D stands for Dynamic. I still think it's a very useful term.

Comment: It is indeed a really usefull term, and one I'm particulary fond of. The problem is that in my experience **lots** of people don't have a clue of what it means. Perhaps we bring it *back to life*?