# Convert code snippet to code block button

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

In the tags I frequent (C# and ASP.NET) the code snippet feature is often used incorrectly. Code snippets do not support ASP.NET controls, inline syntax from ASP.NET Web Forms or Razor, and certainly don't support server side code.

So when I come across those, I edit the question and convert them from code snippets to code blocks. But I've had to do it enough times that I think it's something we can automate, making it quick and painless to fix.

Can we get a button on the edit page that will automatically convert all code snippets to code blocks in a post? Maybe even auto add the edit summary:

> Code snippets only support HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Converted to code block.

Comment: This is really funny... I spend most of my time in the front end web tags, and I very often have to take code blocks and convert them to snippets. Perhaps a toggle button would be helpful. If snippet convert to code block, if code block convert to snippet.

Comment: @apaul34208 Wouldn't code block to snippet be hard? The system will need to detect what code is what and what goes where. I think that's a task only humans could do for now.

Comment: I think better would be a message when you use the code snippet feature saying they only support HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: There are other types of JavaScript that are not runnable in the browser. I suggest: *"Code snippets only support HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that are runnable in a browser. Converted to code block."*

Comment: How about replacing the word *code snippet* with *Minimal Reproducible example*

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm not against a message. That'd be good. But there's already existing questions/answers with invalid code snippets in them that I'd like to clean up. And some people will still ignore the message.

Comment: @ShaunakD The feature under discussion is Code Snippets. I think changing it to "minimal reproducible example" would be very confusing.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274636/code-snippet-as-a-formatting-tool

Comment: @nhahtdh That's nice and I'd like that, but there's still a lot of questions out there I'm sure that need to be cleaned up. This button would make that clean up process faster.

Comment: This is an opinion and not a question, please refrain from adding questions like these on the platform. SO allows to have questions with MVP which can be looked into to provide a solution for any issue you might face.

Comment: @ShubhamArya You do understand this is Meta, right? My question is entirely appropriate here. I get that you're upset I told you your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. I told you that because I've been on this site for years and I'm trying to help you understand how to use the site effectively. Stalking my questions in an attempt to revenge post isn't going to be very productive for you. Stop fighting the advice I give you, learn to listen to feedback - it will go a long way towards helping you on this site and in life in general.

Comment: Duly noted, I accept that I was a little upset. I take your advice and will work on the same. Apologies and Thanks.

Comment: @Shubham awesome, good to hear it. good luck!

Answer (score 23):

```js
I agree with this proposal.

... although I still think the real problem lies in the fact that the UI makes
the snippet feature sound like a general-purpose code block feature.
```

Comment: You are a criminal.

Comment: Well, your code snippet doesn't run. You should post it on the main site to see if someone can solve your problem.

Comment: I'm a little surprised you didn't use the CSS block... ;)