# Option to format/beautify code, or automatically do so

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Many of my edits on Stack Overflow are merely formatting improvements. Adding newlines and indents is what I do at night. However, I wonder if it's possible to automate the process. Especially people who are new to Stack Overflow and/or the language at hand seem to not bother about readable code blocks. However, for us - the people trying to help - it is quite the effort to first make the code readable and then try to answer the question.

As I see it there are two options: either immediately beautify code as soon as someone uses the Code Sample button in the toolbar, or add a Beautify Code button to the toolbar. Beautifying should only be allowed on code snippets.

I understand that an implementation might take some weeks or months to roll out, but there are [many tools available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206441/online-code-beautifier-and-formatter) exactly for this.

For some people this might seem to be a silly problem, but users who are active in the web development department should have encountered this problem many times before. Personally, I especially notice this in the [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29), [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), and [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) tags.

PS: I searched for this question with the keywords "format", "beautify", "formatting code" and didn't get any similar questions. My question is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274636/code-snippet-as-a-formatting-tool?rq=1), but there's been no response for 9 months.

Comment: have you seen this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299236/feedback-requested-code-editor-and-stack-snippets?  You might want to add this there as well

Answer (score 5):

I often use the code editor - it has a tidy:

[image: screenshot]

It is, alas, not available on mobile - however a snippet can be edited by hand in the normal editor but not tidied.

Comment: But the code editor is restricted to JS, HTML and CSS. It would be useful if the *tidy* functionality is extracted and made globally available. Not only for snippets, but also for "normal" code blocks and code of other languages.

Comment: Ah, right. I am only living in JS land :)

Answer (score 4):

I like your idea in general (as long as it stays optional of course), but aside from the implementation problem, another issue that I see is the question about what format should be used.

What I usually do to format the code is to just copy it into an IDE with autoformat, add an additional tab and copy it back to the question. So it is actually not *that* tedious, but still takes some time of course.

Comment: The SO code editor has "Tidy" in it so I use that often

Comment: @mplungjan: Shame on me, I wasn't aware that something like a code editor existed on SO. Can you explain, where it can be found?

Comment: See my answer for fomatting

Comment: @mplungjan: Ok, that explains it - I'm almost exclusively working in c++.

Comment: OP mentioned _sass, css, html, xml, js, php, json categories._

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes and you gave a perfectly good answer. However, I encounter the same problem in non-web-languages (e.g. c#/java,/c/c++...). That is why I answered the OP in the first place and - after your comment - hoped there would be a general purpose code editor for all languages that I just overlooked.

Comment: Right. That would be cool since SO autohighlight them anyway