# Can we add code beautify to stack snippets?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

### tl;dr:

[image]

Stack Snippets are pretty sweet. I find myself using them more and more, where I used to use JSFiddle or Codepen. Kudos to StackOverflow for implementing.

And yet, I still find myself coding JSFiddle, then pasting my code into the snippet. Why? Because JSFiddle has an awesome Tidy button, that turns my horrid code into an amazing piece of art.

So, my request is, **Why can't we have code beautify in Stack Snippets?**

Here is my reasoning:

Snippets are used to display the source code and provide a demo at the same time. Since the purpose of an answer is to provide a solution, and help the OP understand their problem, the logical decision is to make the questions as easy to read and understand as possible. The code doesn't need to look like it was made in notepad.
[image: AHHHHHH]

Compare that atrocity to this:

[image: pretty]

See My point?

Not as important, but you find it all the time where people edit a question/answer to provide the correct formatting. While this might be considered a trivial edit to some, it defiantly shows that users prefer pretty code to ugly code, I especially do.

I am sure there are plenty of others reasons that could be found, but I think the above is enough to justify adding a button and a beautify script (Alright, it might be a bit harder).

#### Can we please add code beautify to stack snippets?

Comment: Similar cross-site question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82671 , http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84718

Comment: @Rizier123 similar, but not about stack snippets. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: What's the difference between stack snippets and whatever the thing that stacks currently uses? (skip line then indent 4 spaces). Is this a tool that would autoformat code in code-blocks? (if so sounds amazing)

Comment: @star2wars3 stack snippets are the HTML, CSS, and Javascript displays that you can add in the editor, or `Ctrl-M`. While auto format for codeblocks would be awesome, it woulds also be much harder, since SE would have to determine what type of code it was, then apply the correct formatting. I think it would be much easier to autoformat three set languages.

Comment: The HTML/CSS/JavaScript stack snippets do have a `Tidy` button that seems to work well.

Comment: Hmm.. We should have that for all types of code, not just HTML / CSS / JS stack snippets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stack-Snippets™ already have a tidy button.

[image]

If you're talking about a tidy button for the post editor, rather than the Stack-Snippet™ editor, you might want to amend your question to clarify that.

Comment: For some reason, that button wasn't appearing for me, seems like I had some problem. I feel really stupid right now.

Comment: I like the idea of a "Tidy" button for the post editor. It would save time while posting [and make our editors' lives easier as well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300271/3345375). Also, it could answer some questions by revealing typos or incorrect brackets.