# Lots of bogus "begin snippet" need to be edited out because of unrelated languages

Tags: discussion

Recently I've noticed a lot of code snippets that have something like this:

```
<! -- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
<! -- language: lang-html -->
<! -- end snippet -->
```

Where the language is completely bogus compared to the question, and as a result all the syntax highlighting is completely messed up.

What is the origin of this? I haven't seen it anywhere in the editor, and it is getting *really* annoying and is very harmful to readability.

Comment: Add Code Snippet button. It's from there.

Comment: There are several feature requests to suppress this for languages that actually don't apply to run snippets.

Comment: [Here is one such conversation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused/296988#296988) on the matter

Comment: Okay, marked as a duplicate then.