# Is it acceptable to edit out "stack snippet" formatting that has no benefit over `code formatting`?

Tags: discussion, support, code-formatting, stack-snippets

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974654/328397) is a bit cluttered by the **code snippet** formatting and offers no value. I want to revert it to traditional grey **code formatting** with no buttons.

[image]

**Question**

- Are there guidelines on how to use this feature (I never knew it existed)?
- Can these guidelines appear in a help sidebar? (for support)

Comment: See also [Stack Snippets being misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused). The consensus seems to be: remove it if it doesn't run (i.e. no valid HTML+CSS+JS).